# Minimum Number of Errors required for BER Curves in Matlab Simulation

Tags: matlab, digital-communications

what should be minimum Number of Errors required for getting BER Curves in Matlab Simulation for different number of transmitted bits ?

Comment: A good rule of thumb is to make sure you have seen around 100 symbol errors.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a fair number of BER simulations and have not found a definitive answer on this. It depends on the error behavior of your channel, Gaussian or some other pdf. My process for AWGN was as follows. First I determine the approximate BER I am expecting. Say that it is 10-3. The inverse of that is 1000 bits. So I would run at least 10x that to start, or a length of 10,000 bits as a minimum. For coded signals, or those with fading, I might use a larger multiplier, such as 50 to 100 times. By watching the error pattern we can often tell if steady state has been achieved. For coded channels with BERs of 10-8 etc., the run lengths quickly become an issue.

This applies to Monte Carlo simulations. You can do semi-analytic methods that do not require such large runs. However semi-analytic methods are generally not that good for non-AWGN channels. Importance sampling is one such semi-analytic method which is used with coded signals. All of these are estimates.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the smoothness of curves required. You can do this in two ways:

1. Fix the number of transmitted data, and change this number to get a smooth curve by detecting more errors.
2. Fix the number of errors to be found, and keep transmitting until you meet this number of errors. However, be aware that in high SNR, the number of errors will be small, and thus you will need to keep looping, which may take forever. You can fix this by breaking the loop when the BER reaches $10^{-5}$, for example.

Hope this helps

Comment: I have confusion that on one hand we are actually trying to find out the PROBABILITY of errors but on the other hand we are fixing it even before simulations, then how is it again a PROBABILITY ?

Comment: We don't fix the probability, we fix the number of errors. To elaborate, suppose you want to find 1000 errors in your transmission. So, you keep transmitting until 1000 errors are found. The number of bits you transmit (let's denote it as N) to find 1000 errors is unknown, so, the probability of error 1000/N is not fixed. This is one approach. The other approach to fix the number of transmitted bits, and then see how many errors you get out of these. Here the number of errors is unknown, and thus the probability of error again is not known. Hope this clarifies your confusion.